# Starting daemon without forking to background

Tags: daemon, emacs-daemon

I want to run an Emacs daemon under [daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).  So I need to create an Emacs process which

1. Basically does `emacs --daemon`
2. Does stay in the foreground
3. Displays the `Messages` buffer (or some other logging info) on *STDOUT*

I have no clue how to do this, so would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: There is a new `--fg-daemon` option in Emacs 26 (refer [Bug#2677](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=2677), https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-11/msg00383.html, https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-05/msg00861.html)